# Makefile with SHELL=/usr/bin/R : handling multilines

Tags: r, shell, makefile

I'm playing with **R** and **Gnu Make** (4.0, the code below won't work with <=3.81) and I'd like to use R instead of a classical shell:

I wrote the following code:

```
.PHONY: all clean
SHELL = /usr/bin/R
.SHELLFLAGS=  --vanilla --no-readline --quiet -e
.ONESHELL:

UCSC=http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg17/database/

all: chr1_gold.txt.gz
    gold <- read.delim(gzfile("$<"))
    head(gold)

chr1_gold.txt.gz:
    download.file("${UCSC}/$@","$@")


clean:
    $(foreach F,chr1_gold.txt.gz,file.remove("$F");)
```

the target **chr1_gold.txt.gz** works fine but not the target "**all**" because there is more than one line:

```
$ /make-4.0/make
download.file("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg17/database//chr1_gold.txt.gz","chr1_gold.txt.gz")
> download.file("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg17/database//chr1_gold.txt.gz","chr1_gold.txt.gz")
trying URL 'http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg17/database//chr1_gold.txt.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 45866 bytes (44 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 44 Kb

> 
> 
gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz"))
head(gold)

ARGUMENT 'head(gold)' __ignored__

> gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz"));\
Error: unexpected input in "\"
Execution halted
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I tried to add a backslash, a semi colon but that doesn't work: how can I fix this ? Can I tell make to pipe a file to the SHELL instead of using an argument (-e string) ?

**EDIT**:

with

```
all: chr1_gold.txt.gz
    gold <- read.delim(gzfile("$<")) \
    head(gold)
```

.

```
read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) \
head(gold)

ARGUMENT 'head(gold)' __ignored__

> gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) \
Error: unexpected input in "gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) \"
Execution halted
```

with ';'

```
all: chr1_gold.txt.gz
    gold <- read.delim(gzfile("$<")) ;
    head(gold)
```

.
    gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) ;
    head(gold)
    ARGUMENT 'head(gold)' **ignored**

```
> gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) ;
> 
>
```

with ';\'

```
all: chr1_gold.txt.gz
    gold <- read.delim(gzfile("$<")) ;\
    head(gold)
```

.

```
ARGUMENT 'head(gold)' __ignored__

> gold <- read.delim(gzfile("chr1_gold.txt.gz")) ;\
Error: unexpected input in "\"
Execution halted
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Where is the `;\` coming from?  Make won't add that so you must be adding it?  You should not have the backslash and semicolon there.  You don't need it if you're using ONESHELL.  What errors do you get without the backslash and semicolon?

Comment: I added some examples with/without ';' and '\'

Comment: If you're using ONESHELL you don't want _either_ backslash _or_ semicolon.  That's the point of ONESHELL: it causes all the recipe lines to be handled to the same shell even without using backslash.  You don't show any example of trying that.

Comment: Heh, I see that SO editor ate my backslash in my first comment.  That was supposed to say _Where is the `;\\` coming from?_

Comment: @MadScientist "You don't show any example of trying that": yes, in my main Makefile, there is no semicolon or backslash after `read.delim`. (?)

Comment: You show the example makefile, but you don't show what errors you get when you use it.  The errors you showed are for a makefile that contains the semicolon-backslash combination.  That's why I was confused in my first comment above; where those came from since they didn't exist in the example makefile you provided.

Comment: ops, I see. bad copy+paste. I changed the first error message. The error was the ~ same.

Comment: The bottom example still shows the `;\\`.  But whatever.

Comment: I think the problem comes from R itself. As far as I can see, R doesn't want to read a -e 'expression' containing a carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this is a problem with R's `-e` option: it appears that unlike the shell's `-e` option, R's version will accept only a single command and ignores embedded newlines (as you suspected).  Unfortunately there's no option in GNU make to have it automatically write a temporary file and send that to the SHELL.  The logistics here are somewhat daunting: how would you specify the name of the file in the shell command?  Or what if you wanted to pipe via stdin?  Etc.  It could be done for sure, but requires some careful consideration of the design.

Currently GNU make requires that the interpreter used for SHELL must be able to accept a multi-line script provided on the command line, that's just the way it is.

The most straightforward way to work with R that I can think of is to put the recipe into a variable using `define`/`enddef` to preserve newlines, then use the new `$(file ...)` function to write it to a file and call R with the name of that file.  You can make this somewhat cleaner with a user-defined variable, but you'll probably have to go back to using /bin/sh as the SHELL.

Comment: thank you. In the end, I wrote a wrapper around R. It works fine: see http://plindenbaum.blogspot.fr/2014/01/parallelizing-rstats-using-make.html

Comment: Re your script; you can save yourself some wear-and-tear on your disk and avoid the need for temp files and cleanup by just piping the input directly: `echo "$R" | R --vanilla --no-readline --quiet`.  Just a thought.

Comment: you're right! :-) I've added your comment in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative is to use "[littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html)"

For example:

```
.PHONY: all
SHELL = /usr/bin/r
.SHELLFLAGS= -e
.ONESHELL:
.SILENT: all

all:
    x <- rnorm(10)
    cat(sd(x), "\n")
```